# stop a network from predicting all ones

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a binary classifier neural network on highly imbalanced data. The class imbalance is around 99%:1%. Even when weighting the data to create a 50-50 sample, there seem to be problems. The network either gets stuck on a low accuracy, or guesses all zeros to get the maximal 99% accuracy.​ ​Setting a lower threshold for the response also doesn't seem to work​. Is there a way to create a cost function that works well with imbalanced classes or one that can mimic gradient boosting? I would like to implement something that learns aggressively on the outliers and penalizes false predictions for zero. I tried modifying the cost function in the following way but it does not improve the algorithm.

```
class QuadraticCost(object):
def fn(output, y):
    if y == 1 and output < 0.5: fun = 100*0.5*np.linalg.norm(output-y)**2
    else: fun = 1*0.5*np.linalg.norm(output-y)**2
    return fun

def delta(z, a, y):
    return (a-y) * sigmoid_prime(z)
```

(In my backpropagation algorithm I use the following total cost function for stochastic gradient descent  with eta equal to the  learning rate,  and lambda is the regularization parameter)

Any ideas on how to modify the cost to penalize false 0s more would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: is there a way to amend the backpropagation algorithm to use a ROC-AUC cost rather than the quadratic one?

Comment: How do your features look like? Can you, as a human, predict the classes from the features? In which range are the features?

Comment: There are ~370 features, and no, I cannot guess what classes the observations would fall into just by inspection. They are sparse and range from 0 to 1 or 0 to 1000. I normalized the data beforehand but still have teh same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. Your cost is additive, meaning that it is just of form

```
L({(x_i,y_i)}, w) = SUM_i l(h(x_i|w), y_i) + C theta(w)
```

where theta is regularization penalty (in your code L2 norm), h(x_i|w) is your prediction for x_i and current parameters w, and l(a,b) is a point-wise cost for giving prediction a when the label is b. Simply change your cost to

```
L({(x_i,y_i)}, w) = SUM_i importance(y_i) * l(h(x_i|w), y_i) + C theta(w)
```

where importance(a) is importance of class a, thus in your case you could use importance(0) = 0.001 and importance(1) = 1, causing network to care about "1" instances 1000x more than "0"s. The additivness makes also computation of gradients extremely simple, as you will just have to multiply gradient for sample i by the very same importance. You can think about it as using two different learning rates - small learning rate for majority class and big one for minority (from mathematical perspective this is pretty much the same). The only difference is when you use minibatches (then this learning rate interpretation is no longer valid, as you have something like weighted average over these learning rates).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. I did a weighting like you suggested with 
```def fn(output, y):
    if output < 0.5: fun = 100*0.5*np.linalg.norm(output-y)**2
    else: fun = 1*0.5*np.linalg.norm(output-y)**2
    return fun``` where importance(0) is 1/100. By updating the gradient do you mean changing the backpropagation method?

Comment: no you did not, you conditioned on **output**, and you should condition on **correct label**. And yes, the crucial thing is a gradient, not value of the cost. Thus you need to actually condition inside your update methods, this is where learning takes place. SGD actually does not use function value, it only cares about the gradient

Comment: simply alternate (in update_mini_batch) the lines with nabla_w and nabla_b updates - you are doing something like `nb+dnb` inside list comprehension - just change it to `nb+dnb*weight[y]` and define weights for particular classes (y's)